# Custom Control in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, button, custom-controls

I have just started to learn WPF.

I have a button with image. like `Image+Text`

```
    <Button Height="67" Name="Button1" Width="228" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Image Source="Images/add.png" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
            <TextBlock Text="  Create Company" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

Now I want to add many more buttons in the above format.
So I have to write the same code again and again.

So I decided to have a customButton to do my job easily.
I tried to create the custom control.

I added a property named Image there.
Now how should I give value to that property?

Am I going on the wrong way?

Comment: kmatyaszek has given a comprehensive answer about how to create a custom control. There is however a quick hack to solve your problem, which uses the `Content` and the `Tag` property to contain the image and text respectively. It would only involve the creation of a Style or DataTemplate resource and would avoid to create a custom or user control, or a derived Button control. I'd write an answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have tutorial [how to create a custom control](http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html).

[1.] Add new item "Custom Control (WPF)" with name "ButtonImg".

After this step, VS create for you two files: "ButtonImg.cs" and "/Themes/Generic.xaml".

[2.] Add few dependency properties to "ButtonImg.cs" file:

I created properties to: image source, text, image width and height.

```
public class ButtonImg : Control
{
    static ButtonImg()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ButtonImg), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ButtonImg)));
    }

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }        
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ButtonImg), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ButtonImg), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public double ImageWidth
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ImageWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageWidthProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageWidth", typeof(double), typeof(ButtonImg), new PropertyMetadata((double)30));

    public double ImageHeight
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ImageHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageHeightProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageHeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageHeight", typeof(double), typeof(ButtonImg), new PropertyMetadata((double)30));
}
```

[3.] In this step you must create Template for your new custom control. So you must edit following file "/Themes/Generic.xaml":

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfButtonImg">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonImg}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonImg}">                  
                    <Button>
                        <Button.Content>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}" 
                                       Height="{TemplateBinding ImageHeight}" Width="{TemplateBinding ImageWidth}" 
                                       Stretch="Uniform" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

[4.] Example of using this new custom control is following:

First you must add appropriate namespace:

```
xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:WpfButtonImg"
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
<MyNamespace:ButtonImg ImageSource="/Images/plug.png" Text="Click me!" />
```

Comment: Can I use public class ButtonImg : Button or public class ButtonImg : ToggleButton Instead of public class ButtonImg : Control?

Comment: @Vishal, yes of course. Version with base class `Button` is better because you have e.g. Click event.